# Serialize BasicDBObject using non-extended JSON

Tags: java, json, mongodb, mongo-java-driver

I have some Mongo database object:

```
BasicDBObject obj = mongoTemplate.findById(id, BasicDBObject.class, "data");
```

If I convert this to JSON, I get extended json:

```
{"_id": { "$oid" : "..."}, "someDate": {"$date": "..."}}
```

I would like basic, simple JSON, so I can plug it into the language of my choice (JS/Python/Ruby/etc):

```
{"_id": "...", "someDate": "..."}
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: What is spring mongo and mongo driver version ?

Comment: Not sure, but it's flexible. If it's doable in any version I can switch to that version.